# Ways to input multiple duplicate values into a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to generate and input multiple duplicate values into a list like so,

```
look_back_timeseries_to_supervised_learning = 6
print(('None,'*(look_back_timeseries_to_supervised_learning-1))[:-1].split(','))
```

Which gives me,

```
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
```

How can I get,

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Just do [None]*look_back_timeseries_to_supervised_learning

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner in Python! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[None] * 5
```

Is that what you want? (Change the file for whatever variable holds the number of nones you want)

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
l = ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']
```

You can change the list using:

```
l = [None if x == 'None' else x for x in l]
```